# Is this interference and if it is how is it being caused in these pictures

Tags: visible-light, interference, diffraction

I link 3  figures below [image] .

[image]
[image]

The white bulbs were on my backside on the ceiling as is visible in their reflection in the television. I was sitting almost between (length wise) the bulbs and the television. I took the photographs of their reflection in the LCD.

What are these crosses of rainbow coloured fringes?

Is it interference or diffraction?

And whatever of the 2 it is, how is it happening?

Why only 2 crosses of coloured fringes in the reflection of every bulb , when the angle of each bulb is different?

The bulbs were on my backside so Lloyd's mirror like explanation isn't possible.

Why only 2  crosses of coloured fringes are appearing in the reflection of all the bulbs when they are at different angles?

How is this being caused?

I don't know whether stack exchange is the right place to ask this question by uploading the pictures related to the question , but I couldn't find anyone who could give a reasoning and so I posted it here.

Ever more interesting is that the reflection of the CFL visible in 1st and 2nd pictures is not showing any such pattern.

Comment: Duplicate? although the pictures are much better here.  http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/160319/

Comment: @Farcher  But why are only 2 crosses forming in the reflection of every bulb and what is causing them ? How is interference happening here ?

Comment: Here is another post.  http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/167892/