# Why does yellow light shining on the tv diffract all spectrum of light?

Tags: optics, visible-light, everyday-life, diffraction

This was an image I took during the evening time on the led tv , I had two questions the first was why was the tv giving off a x pattern of the diffracted light which constitutes primary white light color? While as mirror doesn't do this. But I learnt about this "diffraction grating" in another stack question.

But my second question is , why is the mainly yellow light from the sun as due to Rayleigh scattering make the same x with the primary color distribution rather than having more red-orange colors. Some unwanted wavelength of light could have crept in but the majority is yellow right ? Am I missing something here ?
[image]

top left light is from sun through the window
the center light is from the phone's flash

Comment: The "yellow" light of the sun contains all visible colors, as you have just found out like Newton did.

Comment: but shouldn't the yellow light reaching to our eye(in evening due to rayleigh scattering) be of lower wavelengths and hence could only contain some partial wavelengths?

Comment: The color balance changes to some extent, yes, but there is still blue there. Just slightly less. Human perception of color is a complex subject, but it is not like a diffraction grating.

Comment: so this light is not being diffraction grated ?? Also thanks for the yellow light answer
https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/381233/why-does-light-reflected-from-an-led-tv-screen-make-a-sharp-x-pattern here there was a talk about diffraction grating

Comment: Sure it is diffracted, so you see the blue content, while your eye after processing the signals from various cones has assigned ‘yellowish’ to the overall ‘color’, not ‘here is the full spectrum’ which your eyes can’t do anyway.

Comment: ah makes sense thank you very much !